# How can realize border radius like egg

Tags: html, css

Can I realize this style of image with css3?

[image]

I have set this style of border in

```
.image img {border-radius: 40% 60% 60% 40%/50%; }
```

, but I think that isn't right one.

Comment: you can use clip property from css3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create something similar with pseudo-elemnts. First to create that shape you can use `border-radius` and then you can add large `box-shadow` for gray area and one more for that blue shadow.

```css
.egg {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.egg:after {
  content: '';
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  box-shadow: -7px -7px 0px 0px #67BEF9, 0px 0px 0px 400px #ECECEC;
  border-radius: 204px 109px 106px 212px / 125px 110px 110px 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="egg">
  <img src="https://st.hzcdn.com/simgs/25e1d6580f5a3538_4-1972/traditional-staircase.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! :) But when I try to set width 400px (more than 350), I can't save this model

Comment: I can't create jsfiddle. but can you set width:500px; and height:450, to try with the same form ?

Comment: On parent element or on pseudo-element?

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a little code for egg . It is created by border-radius

```css
#egg {
       display:block;
       width: 126px;
       height: 180px;
       background-color: red;
       -webkit-border-radius: 63px 63px 63px 63px / 108px 108px 72px 72px;
       border-radius:         50%  50%  50%  50%  / 60%   60%   40%  40%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="egg"></div>
```

Comment: You  can use any image with "background-image", and remove "background-color" from this snippet

Comment: yes, but my image is a little different from egg, you can see my image above :) Thank's :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="height=;height: 505px;width: 655px;background-color: #ececec;">
    <img src="test_img.png" height="500" width="650" style="border-top-left-radius: 100% 100%;border-top-right-radius: 100% 160%;border-bottom-left-radius: 135% 100%;border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Try out this, may be helpfull